# Значение null для объектов. Как это выглядит?

Tags: javascript, объекты, null

Читаю про цикл `for in`:

> Если переменная, представляющая объект, будет иметь значение `null` или `undefined` цикл не выполнится ни разу.

**Про undefined:** я думаю для того, чтобы значение объекта было undefined, надо просто в нем ничего не писать.

```
let object = {
//ничего здесь нет
}
```

**Про null:** ну а про `null` не понятно. Мы же не можем сделать вот так:

```
let object = {
null
} //--> Синтаксическая ошибка
```

Comment: `let object = null;`

Comment: Вы путаете объект и переменную. "Если переменная, представляющая объект, будет иметь значение null". Переменная иметь значение.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Так это ж просто обычная переменная, которой вы присвоили значение `null`. Объект вроде как должен создаваться либо с помощью фигурных скобок, либо с помощью `new Object()`

Comment: undefined, переменная объявлена, но ей не присвоено никакого значения `let list;`  null, это значение перменной, такое-же как true, 1 или "это текст" `let list = null`.

Comment: «Если переменная, представляющая объект, будет иметь значение `null` или `undefined` цикл не выполнится ни разу.» **=>** Если есть какая-нибудь переменная, которая предназначена для хранения объекта, но в данный момент она хранит не объект, а значение `null` или `undefined`, то цикл не выполнится ни разу.

Comment: @wololo `let object = {
                  }` скажите, а здесь что происходит? Я так понимаю, что переменная `object` не равна `undefined`, потому что внутрь переменной мы всё-таки положили объект. Просто свойств нет, объект пустой. Правильно?

Comment: @Eva, всё верно.